# docker-compose throws errors by starting mariadb for an private nextcloud installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, lets-encrypt, nextcloud

I have an nextcloud installation based on an docker-compose.yml which was running smoothely since at least 6 months. All of a sudden I couldn't reach the frontend anymore (got an 500).

Honestly I do not know what happened and need help.

What I did until now ...

I logged and did an pull and afterwards an docker-copmuse up -d.
It seems that mariadb cannot be started anymore ....

The error is:

`Removing nextcloud-letsencrypt
Removing nextcloud-mariadb
Recreating 4378ae40b393_nextcloud-mariadb ...
Recreating 4378ae40b393_nextcloud-mariadb     ... error
Recreating 30867336c79f_nextcloud-letsencrypt ...`

ERROR: for 4378ae40b393_nextcloud-mariadb  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/c26f550b873f2c0c37Recreating 30867336c79f_nextcloud-letsencrypt ... error

ERROR: for 30867336c79f_nextcloud-letsencrypt  Cannot start service letsencrypt: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/487b874d0bff9bf4810cb908fa3d27c955fb1d65dd0f07c727f4b5667f24767d/devices.allow: operation not permitted\\"\"": unknown

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/c26f550b873f2c0c376f5174ce4b1f64e536e8b876bf3438bb3ef77f16b76426/devices.allow: operation not permitted\\"\"": unknown

ERROR: for letsencrypt  Cannot start service letsencrypt: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/487b874d0bff9bf4810cb908fa3d27c955fb1d65dd0f07c727f4b5667f24767d/devices.allow: operation not permitted\\"\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
hasp@h2800129:~/myCloud$ ERROR: for 4378ae40b393_nextcloud-mariadb  Cannot start service db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/c26f550b873f2c0c37Recreating 30867336c79f_nextcloud-letsencrypt ... error

For the ones who can help me as a thumb user y docker-compose.yml was not touched within the last months ... And looks like this

`version: '3'`

services:

proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./uploadsize.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/uploadsize.conf:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_root_password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped

app:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
      - proxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - ./app/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./app/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - ./app/data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=nextcloud.hasp.de
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=nextcloud.hasp.de
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=hannes@hasp.de
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:

Comment: I tried a docker -run <code>docker run --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_root_password -d mariadb</code> which resulted in <code>docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:367: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\\"failed to write c 10:200 rwm to devices.allow: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker/29dcb551f1329d91987cbaab3611f4187ca08508539ddc4021efb90bb84c160b/devices.allow: operation not permitted\\\"\"": unknown.
</code>

Comment: GRRRR - I didn't trust the whole thing - so I did the old IT trick 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo reboot

and everything works - but why ...